# How do I show the Auto ID from the SharePoint list on the Detail page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've got a list of issues and I'm using the auto id to identify the issue.  I would like the number to show up on the detail page for each item, as well as possibly adding it as a read only field on the edit page of the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the dispform.aspx / editform.aspx through SharePoint Designer. use a readonly SharePoint TextField to display the ID.